# Fabric data successfully sent but not appearing after app bundle identifier (and signature) was modified

Tags: ios, google-fabric, fabric.io

I had to modify the bundle identifier (and the signature) of one of my iOS apps. I kept all the previous Fabric related code in the app as it was before.

I can't see any data for the new version of the app in Fabric.
  I checked it: based on the log output of Fabric, the requests are successfully sent.

How could I fix this issue?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: a. Does the new app bundle show up in Fabric's dashboard ? b. Have you forced a crash to check if the data is being sent correctly ?

Comment: Thanks for stepping @nathan. You'll need to build and run the app in the simulator to get it to onboard to your Fabric dashboard. It'll appear as a new app. Check out fabric.io/kits for some help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see this in the log :

```html
Aug  7 15:06:21 me-MBP assertiond[37177]: Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.ios.myapp[0xb044][37177]
Aug  7 15:06:21 me-MBP SpringBoard[37172]: [com.mycompany.ios.myapp] Bootstrap complete with label: UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.ios.myapp[0xb044][37177]
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: assertion failed: 16G29 14E269: libxpc.dylib + 64131 [624BAF4F-2E03-34F8-ACBA-970B04637786]: 0x7d
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.3 (120)
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Crashlytics] Running on iOS Simulator (iPhone), 10.3.0 (16G29)
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Crashlytics:Crash] Reporting is disabled
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Crashlytics] Crash reporting could not be initialized
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Answers] Initialized
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP assertiond[37177]: client <BSProcessHandle: 0x7fe76dc04100; MyApp:54744; valid: YES> HWM increased to 1 because of <BKProcessAssertion: 0x7fe76e906f50; "io.answers.RecordEvent" (finishTask:180s); id:…5C9E39B8B4CC>
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
     "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.3";
     "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.8.3";
     "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.6.11";
 }
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Crashlytics:Crash] WARNING: CLSLog has been used before (or concurrently with) Crashlytics initialization and cannot be recorded. The message was: 
 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] line 115 $ Used language: en
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] line 115 $ Used language: en
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Answers] Answers is disabled. Cleaning up.
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 10
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: Could not load the "G2A_Toolbar_Logo" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.mycompany.ios.myapp"
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: applicationDidBecomeActive - stopBackgroundTask
Aug  7 15:06:22 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: stopBackgroundTask
Aug  7 15:06:23 me-MBP pasted[54287]: BundleID com.mycompany.ios.myapp from team GFNFVT632V is requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general
Aug  7 15:06:23 me-MBP pasted[54287]: ...requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general completed. Error: (null)
Aug  7 15:06:23 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: OutOfSessionController -setDelegate: delegate updated
Aug  7 15:06:23 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
Aug  7 15:06:23 me-MBP MyApp[54744]: [Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
Aug  7 15:06:35 me-MBP SpringBoard[37172]: [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Aug  7 15:06:35 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  7 15:06:35 me-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D45F40B7-FFEF-4B8A-AA17-A8B7DBB7637D.launchd_sim[37155] (UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.ios.myapp[0xb044][37177][54744]): Service exited due to Illegal instruction: 4
Aug  7 15:06:35 me-MBP backboardd[37173]: [Common] Unable to get short BSD proc info for 54744: No such process
Aug  7 15:06:35 me-MBP backboardd[37173]: [Common] Unable to get proc info for 54744: Undefined error: 0
Aug  7 15:06:37 me-MBP assertiond[37177]: Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.ios.myapp[0xb044][37177]
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP assertiond[37177]: Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.ios.myapp[0x10d3][37177]
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP SpringBoard[37172]: [com.mycompany.ios.myapp] Bootstrap complete with label: UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.ios.myapp[0x10d3][37177]
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: assertion failed: 16G29 14E269: libxpc.dylib + 64131 [624BAF4F-2E03-34F8-ACBA-970B04637786]: 0x7d
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.3 (120)
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Crashlytics] Running on iOS Simulator (iPhone), 10.3.0 (16G29)
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Crashlytics:Crash] Reporting is disabled
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Crashlytics] Crash reporting could not be initialized
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Answers] Initialized
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP assertiond[37177]: client <BSProcessHandle: 0x7fe76e909f10; MyApp:54755; valid: YES> HWM increased to 1 because of <BKProcessAssertion: 0x7fe76dc036c0; "io.answers.RecordEvent" (finishTask:180s); id:…FE6B9B144203>
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
     "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.3";
     "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.8.3";
     "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.6.11";
 }
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Crashlytics:Crash] WARNING: CLSLog has been used before (or concurrently with) Crashlytics initialization and cannot be recorded. The message was: 
 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] line 115 $ Used language: en
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] line 115 $ Used language: en
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 10
Aug  7 15:06:42 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: Could not load the "G2A_Toolbar_Logo" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.mycompany.ios.myapp"
Aug  7 15:06:43 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Answers] Answers is disabled. Cleaning up.
Aug  7 15:06:43 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
Aug  7 15:06:43 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: applicationDidBecomeActive - stopBackgroundTask
Aug  7 15:06:43 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: stopBackgroundTask
Aug  7 15:06:43 me-MBP pasted[54287]: BundleID com.mycompany.ios.myapp from team GFNFVT632V is requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general
Aug  7 15:06:43 me-MBP pasted[54287]: ...requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general completed. Error: (null)
Aug  7 15:06:43 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: OutOfSessionController -setDelegate: delegate updated
Aug  7 15:06:47 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
Aug  7 15:06:47 me-MBP MyApp[54755]: [Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
```

Comment: Hi, Can you make sure you run Fabric.with before any other calls to the SDKs? It seems like that is the issue here. Thanks!

Comment: I have these calls in - application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: [[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES]; [Fabric with:@[[Answers class], [Crashlytics class]]]; and nothing else. (I've deleted all the CLS_LOG(...) calls.)

Again : as I mentioned everything has been working and is currently working just fine before I've updated the product bundle identifier...